# Navigation model question

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, page-lifecycle

I'm developing a Windows Phone 7 application and I have a doubt.

Imagine I have three pages: PageOne, PageTwo and PageThree. And I do the following:

Application starts on PageOne. From PageOne I go to PageTwo. On PageTwo I press Back Button and I come back to PageOne. And now, I navigate from PageOne to PageThree.

My question is: is PageTwo in Page Stack when I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PageTwo is no longer in the stack because you navigated to a new page after navigating back.

The page stack went through the following changes (square brackets mark the current page; pages outside the app are not included):

```
Start Application
   [PageOne]

Navigate to PageTwo
   PageOne, [PageTwo]

Back
   [PageOne], PageTwo

Navigate to PageThree
   PageOne, [PageThree]
```